# How does electron movement affect reflection and refraction of electromagnetic waves?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

I know that electron movement affects the direction of emission, which is why there is no reflection at Brewster's angle. Can someone say how to predict direction of emission using electron movement and can we control electron movement by manipulating the properties of the EM wave like changing the phase, amplitude, negating the EM wave equation.

Comment: Good question I would be interested in the answers.

Comment: Prediction of emission to various directions is possible, but requires knowledge of EM theory and software to do demanding calculations. The directionality effect of several phase locked emitters is used, for example, in phased arrays.

Comment: Can we manipulate the direction of emission using the e.m wave?

Comment: If an object reflects e.m wave in one direction for a certain wave which has its electric field oscillating in a certain direction,if we change the direction of oscillation by 90 degrees will the material refract or mostly refract because the electron motion due to electric field changes and therefore the direction of emission changes right?.Also tell your way to increase refraction over reflection.Thank You.

Comment: Two ways to decrease reflection and increase refraction through a transparent material like glass is to decrease the angle of incident light and make it more head on. Or change the thickness of the glass. Partial reflection can be anywhere between zero and 16% of the light depending on the thickness.

Comment: How to increase transmittance for metals?

Comment: @Anns One way to increase transmittance is to have lower frequency photons.

Comment: How to calculate transmittance intensity for infrared photons,Also is there any other way to increase transmittance.Does polarization increase transmittance?

Comment: Also can we make infrared photon not interact with conductors,What is the requirement for a photon to interact metal atoms and electron?.